# Pseudo-differential DAC output to single ended

Tags: dac, differential, single-ended

I have a Cirrus Logic CS43198 DAC with pseudo differential outputs.

Is there a simple passive circuit to change them to single ended outputs?

Comment: what's a pseudo-differential output? Voltage or Current DAC?

Comment: 1) what DAC, include a link to the datasheet 2) include a schematic. 3) Consider that any **differential** signal is essentially two **single ended signals** with 180 degrees phase difference.

Comment: I bet you haven't lol.

Comment: This is a voltage DAC .WM CS43198

Comment: Op does not seem interested in helping us so...

Comment: I have found out that the only way to change a differential (even pseudo) signal to single ended is using an opamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CS43198_F1 data sheet](https://d3uzseaevmutz1.cloudfront.net/pubs/proDatasheet/CS43198_F1.pdf) has a certain vague section called *Analogue Signal Conditioning* on page 10 with a dashed outline that could shed light on the application if the details of how the **REFA** and **REFB** pins were connected through were shown.

The [CS4353_F3 data sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/76/cs4353_f3-293696.pdf) hints on page 12 with a similarly positioned and shaded section that the **AOUT_REF** pin is directly connected to the headphone ground.

Both datasheets do show ground connections at the headphone jack.  The question is must this ground be floating (is it even ESD safe to propose such a thing) or can it be tied to some local ground.

The second datasheet on page 13 makes a strong case for the use of the **AOUT_REF** being rather flexible including connecting it to a local ground point.  If one can extrapolate the functionality from a single to a double reference pin and assume *Cirrus Logic* means the same thing in both products with their term *Pseudo differential* then we might be forgiven for thinking that single ended operation is quite possible.

Comment: "8.3 REFA and REFB Routing
For best interchannel isolation performance, REFA and REFB must be routed independently to the headphone connector
reference pin. The **REFA and REFB are electrically connected to system’s ground plane through via at the headphone
connector ground pin**.